# Apple tvOS UX: Browsing a video playlist with the remote control

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

This is more related to the UX of the actual Apple TV device.

After building up a video playlist of 3 `mediaItem`, how can I get to the next `mediaItem` using the remote control?

Comment: Add some detail to your question. Perhaps a screenshot or drawing may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing your app in TVMLJS, it seems the skip functionality is not supported yet.

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/66628#66628

Comment: This answer is confusing. I don't want to skip to the next video using JS. I just wan't to skip to the next video using the remote control.

Comment: Perhaps your question isn't quite clear. You say you've built a video playlist, I assume programmatically and you'd like the user to be able to skip to the next mediaItem in the playlist?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the user to be able to skip to the next mediaItem in the playlist *using the remote* as stated.